# Is there a way to count the length and occurrences of repeated elements in a string?

Tags: python, string, sequence, repeat, string-length

I have this long string:

```
string = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFABCABCABCBACBCABCBCABCABCBACBFFFFFACBCABCAFFF'
```

I want to count the occurrences of repeated 'F' sequences and their length. In this example, there would be 3 repeated instances of 'F', and the length of each instance would be 21, 5, and 3, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> string = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFABCABCABCBACBCABCBCABCABCBACBFFFFFACBCABCAFFF'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [len(list(group)) for char, group in groupby(string) if char == "F"]
[21, 5, 3]
```

`groupby` takes any iterable and forms groups of equal items, yielding tuples of a single instance of the item value and a "group" iterable of the actual items.

The above iteration over a `groupby` call gives you groups of equal letters, filters for those where the letter was F, and converts the groups to lists in order to be able to easily get their `len`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match consecutive occurrences of a specific character.

```py
import re
string = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFABCABCABCBACBCABCBCABCABCBACBFFFFFACBCABCAFFF'
res = [len(s) for s in re.findall('F+', string)]
print(res)
```

Or, to find consecutive consecutive occurrences of any character:

```py
res = [len(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', string)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic but easily understandable solution:

```
string = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFABCABCABCBACBCABCBCABCABCBACBFFFFFACBCABCAFFF"
streak = 0
for i in range(0,len(string)):
   if string[i] == "F":
        streak = streak + 1
        if i == len(string) - 1 or string[i+1] != "F":
            print(streak, end=" ")
            streak = 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).